# DOM Manipulation: How to Create a Text Node on Button Click

Tags: javascript, createtextnode

```js
"use strict";

var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");

myButton.onclick = function (){
 var newNode = document.createTextNode("Blueberry");
 var item = document.getElementId("myList").childNodes[0]; 
  console.log(item);
  item.replaceChild(newNode,item.childNodes[0]);

}
```

```css
#myButton {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Learning the Basics of How DOM Functions</h1>

<h3>
What is DOM?
</h3>

<p id="intro">
DOM stands for "Document Object Model" and it is a plaform (as well as a language-netural interface) that allows programs and scripts to dynamically access and update the content, structure, and style of a document.
<br>
<br>
Visit <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp">this page </a> if you want a further explanation.
</p>

<h3>
Test Your Knowledge:
</h3>
<p>
The purpose of this homework exercise is to introduce you to some examples of DOM manipulation within the HTML. Let's get started!
</p>

<h4>
Part 1
</h4>

<p>
Write some lines of code so that when you click on the button below, one of the values in the list gets replaced without another value.
<br>

<button type="button" id="myButton">Click This to Replace</button>

<ul id="myList">
  <li>
    Apple
  </li>
  <li>
    Watermelon
  </li>
  <li>
    Pumpkin
  </li>
  <li>
    Strawberry
  </li>
  <li>
    Kiwi
  </li>
</ul>
<b>Replace the item that doesn't belong with something that does.</b>
</p>
```

I created a `createTextNode()` function to create a text node `onClick` of a `<button>` element, however, it's not working as expected.

**My Goal:** `onClick` - I want to replace an item from the list I've created using the `createTextNode` function whenever the `<button>` is clicked.

Here's the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sireeena/tpLxfs1d/71/).

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: afaik the on "lick" event is not implemented ... try to lick the monitor to see if it works :)

Comment: Please add your code to your question, with the unnecessary parts removed, rather than just a JsFiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

Start by calling methods which exist:

- `onclick` instead of `onlick`
- `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementId`
- Use `children` rather than `childNodes` since childNodes includes things like code comments.

You can simplify the code to just use textContent rather than createTextNode -

```
var item = document.getElementById("myList").children[0];
item.textContent = 'Blueberry'; // or innerHTML will do
```

Look at your developer console for errors to see what you've done wrong and add console.log's to check if your callback is being called on click.

While you're at it change your myButton to an actual `<button>`

Answer (score 0):

Change `myButton.onlick` to `myButton.onclick` and change `document.getElementId` to `document.getElementById`.
Also, remove the space between the `ul` and the first `li` because that space is being counted as a child node.

This:

```
<ul>
<li>
...
</li>
</ul>
```

should be:

```
<ul><li>
...
</li>
</ul>
```

```js
"use strict";

var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");

myButton.onclick = function (){
 var newNode = document.createTextNode("Blueberry");
 var item = document.getElementById("myList").childNodes[0];
  item.replaceChild(newNode,item.childNodes[0]);

}
```

```css
#myButton {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Learning the Basics of How DOM Functions</h1>

<h3>
What is DOM?
</h3>

<p id="intro">
DOM stands for "Document Object Model" and it is a plaform (as well as a language-netural interface) that allows programs and scripts to dynamically access and update the content, structure, and style of a document.
<br>
<br>
Visit <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp">this page </a> if you want a further explanation.
</p>

<h3>
Test Your Knowledge:
</h3>
<p>
The purpose of this homework exercise is to introduce you to some examples of DOM manipulation within the HTML. Let's get started!
</p>

<h4>
Part 1
</h4>

<p>
Write some lines of code so that when you click on the button below, one of the values in the list gets replaced without another value.
<br>

<div id = "myButton">Click This to Replace</div>

<ul id="myList"><li>
    Apple
  </li>
  <li>
    Watermelon
  </li>
  <li>
    Pumpkin
  </li>
  <li>
    Strawberry
  </li>
  <li>
    Kiwi
  </li>
</ul>
<b>Replace the item that doesn't belong with something that does.</b>
</p>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vanebwds/

You can make your code simpler by setting the `textContent` of the first `li` element of the `ul` instead of using `replaceChild`.

You can use `document.querySelector('#myList li');` to get the first `li` inside the element with the id of `myList` to set the `textContent` of.

```js
"use strict";

var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");

myButton.onclick = function (){
 var item = document.querySelector('#myList li');
  //gets the first li contained by #myList
  item.textContent = "Blueberry";

}
```

```css
#myButton {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Learning the Basics of How DOM Functions</h1>

<h3>
What is DOM?
</h3>

<p id="intro">
DOM stands for "Document Object Model" and it is a plaform (as well as a language-netural interface) that allows programs and scripts to dynamically access and update the content, structure, and style of a document.
<br>
<br>
Visit <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp">this page </a> if you want a further explanation.
</p>

<h3>
Test Your Knowledge:
</h3>
<p>
The purpose of this homework exercise is to introduce you to some examples of DOM manipulation within the HTML. Let's get started!
</p>

<h4>
Part 1
</h4>

<p>
Write some lines of code so that when you click on the button below, one of the values in the list gets replaced without another value.
<br>

<div id = "myButton">Click This to Replace</div>

<ul id="myList"><li>
    Apple
  </li>
  <li>
    Watermelon
  </li>
  <li>
    Pumpkin
  </li>
  <li>
    Strawberry
  </li>
  <li>
    Kiwi
  </li>
</ul>
<b>Replace the item that doesn't belong with something that does.</b>
</p>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b4whmup5/

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @Dominic said:

Your JS code should look like this:

```
"use strict";

var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");

myButton.onclick = function () {
    var newNode = document.createTextNode("Blueberry");
    var item = document.getElementById("myList").childNodes[0]; 
    item.replaceChild(newNode,item.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Your HTML Code should look like this:

```
<h1>Learning the Basics of How DOM Functions</h1>

<h3>What is DOM?</h3>

<p id="intro">
DOM stands for "Document Object Model" and it is a plaform (as well as a language- 
netural interface) that allows programs and scripts to dynamically access and update 
the content, structure, and style of a document.
<br>
<br>
Visit <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp">this page </a> if you 
want a further explanation.
</p>

<h3>Test Your Knowledge:</h3>
<p>
The purpose of this homework exercise is to introduce you to some examples of DOM 
manipulation within the HTML. Let's get started!
</p>

<h4>Part 1</h4>

<p>
Write some lines of code so that when you click on the button below, one of the 
values in the list gets replaced without another value.
</p>
<br>

<button type="button" id="myButton">Click This to Replace</button>

<ul id="myList">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Watermelon/li>
  <li>Pumpkin</li>
  <li>Strawberry/li>
  <li>Kiwi</li>
</ul>
<b>Replace the item that doesn't belong with something that does.</b>
```

Comment: thanks everyone for all the response and tidbits! Obviously I'm new to JS, learning as I go.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much everyone! I've updated to this, however for some reason the createTextNode is still not populating. Not sure what is wrong still?

```
"use strict";

var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");

myButton.onclick = function (){
    var newNode = document.createTextNode("Blueberry");
    var item = document.getElementById("myList").childNodes[3]; 
    item.replaceChild(newNode,item.childNodes[3]);

}
```

HTML

```
<p>
Write some lines of code so that when you click on the button below, one of the values in the list gets replaced without another value.
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" id=myButton>Click This to Replace</button>

<ul id="myList">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Watermelon</li>
  <li>Pumpkin</li>
  <li>Strawberry</li>
  <li>Kiwi</li>
</ul>
<b>Replace the item that doesn't belong with something that does.</b>
</p>
```